# Visible method for workbook

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm using a macro to send an email, and I have to display the email 'cause I want to paste a picture in the body of the email. I'm using this code
    aEmail.Display
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    SendKeys "^v", True
    DoEvents
But then I want the Excel to reappear after the "ctrl+v", but I can't do it.
I tried to use thisworkbook.activate but the window won't show up, I also tried to be creative and used aEmail.Display False (it won't return an error but it won't hide the email neither)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

Call VBA.AppActivate("Excel", False)

Comment: Hello D_Bester, sorry for the long delay, but I don't have internet access during the WE, so I just saw your answer, it it worked fine.
I used the command:
AppActivate("NAME_OF_THE_FILE")
Thank you for the answer!